# flutter how to print value from array

Tags: flutter

I am calling some data throught http request issue is i need to print some value but dont know how can i do this

i need to print the 'LON' and 'LAT' Value but dont know how can i do this

right now its showing this error

```
E/flutter (27280): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
E/flutter (27280): Receiver: null
E/flutter (27280): Tried calling: []("lon")
```

Comment: try `data['location']['lon']`

Comment: @Tuqay try but its showing same error

Answer (score 0):

The "location" field is an object, not an array, so you should try:

```
print(data['location']['lon']);
print(data['location']['lat']);
```

Comment: more correctly, the `location` field is a `map`

Comment: @Sisir yes, in Dart that's a map, but speaking of the JSON structure in general the value of the "location" field is a (JSON) object...anyway, that's correct in both case :)

Comment: I have try this also but its showing Tried calling: []("lon").

Comment: Could you check your json responce and see if it has a field `location`. Seems like `data['location']` this is evaluating to null because this key is not there

Answer (score 0):

There is no `array` in your responce data. It's a `json` which you have converted to a `map` using `var data = json.decode(res.body.toString());`

Now to access data from the map, you use the appropriate key combinations. For example for your case it should be:

```
data['location']['lon'];
data['location']['lat'];
```

Comment: i have try this also but its showing Tried calling: []("lon")

Comment: i have added my api inq uestion you can run also i try on dart pad showing same error